# I Need to change the BackColor of my DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am sutck on this for a few days now but i cant get it right....

So Please help me!
this is what i have right now:

My datagridView Is bound to a database

can anyone please help me?

`DateTime FactuurDatum = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                  int termijn = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());

    DateTime finalDate = FactuurDatum.AddDays((double)termijn);`

```
              if (finalDate > DateTime.Now)
              {
              }
              else
              {
                  row.Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
              }</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .defaultcellstyle.backcolor. It works for us.

Comment: But i just want to color a single Cell.
and i tried that for the whole row but it doesnt work

I can not change any cellstyle....
'
that's so weird

Comment: grid.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; works for the whole row for me... But this is for the whole row, not an individual cell.

Comment: We are using this to display red for expired dates and yellow for products which will expire soon.

Comment: i tried that too but it doesnt work at all 

I never change to color of the row

Comment: Try it once more after your grid is fully displayed. Instead of setting the color during fill out, fill it up, display and then loop through all rows and then set the color.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the backcolor of the entire grid do this:

```
        GridView1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
```

Comment: just want to change the color of a cell

but my grid is databoud so i dont know if it will work then

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a DataGridView and added 5 columns to it and written the following code in page_load event.

```
//Code to insert dummy records...            
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
     "COl1-" + i.ToString(),
     "COl2-" + i.ToString(),
     "COl3-" + i.ToString(),
     "COl4-" + i.ToString(),
     "COl5-" + i.ToString()
     );
}


//Set the Background color to cell
bool isBackColorSet = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
     foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
     {
          if (!isBackColorSet)
          {
              c.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
          }
          isBackColorSet = !isBackColorSet;
     }
}
```